# ionic app did not remain the same route state

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I had a ionic app with initial route "tab.dash",
everything works fine when switch back and then to other apps in short time.

However when I leave my iPhone several hours alone and then start my ionic app
in the Home screen, I find that the app shows the initial route but not the last view route.

It seems that the app has been restart due to idle in the background too long.
How can I fix the issue?
Does iOS automatically shut my app down since idle in the background too long?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't exist any default functionality to do that. So.. you need to persist elsewhere (localStorage for example) the last view/state and redirect to it when the app lunch.

Yes, iOS could automatically close your app when it run in background.

Comment: Thanks. But I did not close the app, does iOS do some memory management by default?